# conditional replaceAll java

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have html code with img src tags pointing to urls. Some have mysite.com/myimage.png as src others have mysite.com/1234/12/12/myimage.png. I want to replace these urls with a cache file path. Im looking for something like this.

```
String website = "mysite.com"    
String text = webContent.replaceAll(website+ "\\d{4}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}", String.valueOf(cacheDir));
```

This code however does not work when the url does not have the extra date stamp at the end. Does anyone know how i might achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "extra date stamp"? How does it not work? Can you show some examples of inputs that behave unexpectedly?

Comment: Do you want something like `"(\\d{4}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2})?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
mysite\.com/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)?
```

here `?` means zero or more occurance

---

**Note:** use escape character `\.` for dot match because `.(dot)` is already used in regex

Sample code :

```
String[] webContents = new String[] { "mysite.com/myimage.png",
        "mysite.com/1234/12/12/myimage.png" };

for (String webContent : webContents) {
    String text = webContent.replaceAll("mysite\\.com/(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}/)?",
            String.valueOf("mysite.com/abc/"));
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

output:

```
mysite.com/abc/myimage.png
mysite.com/abc/myimage.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a forward slash between the `website.com` and the first 4 digits.

```
String text = webContent.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(website) + "/\\d{4}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}", String.valueOf(cacheDir));
```

I'd also recommend using a literal for your `website.com` value (the `Pattern.quote` part).

Finally you are also missing the last forward slash after the last two digits so it won't be replaced, but that may be on purpose...

Comment: you are missing ending `/`. OP wants **This code however does not work when the url does not have the extra date stamp at the end**

Comment: what about `dot` present in `website` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String text = webContent.replaceAll("(?<="+website+")(.*)(?=\\/)", 
                                    String.valueOf(cacheDir));
```